# Missing initial values when another field has required=True

Tags: python, django, django-forms

One can set default values using the [`initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.Field.initial) parameter. However, for some reason, this initial value is not given when another field has the `required=True` parameter. How do I set initial values in this case? I want to set the boxes to have the default value of true instead of false.

Code example:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    #search what?
    titles = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=True)
    abstracts = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=True)
    keywords = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=True)
    names = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=True)
    affiliations = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=False)

    #input
    search = forms.CharField(max_length=500, required=True, label="")
```

Comment: i'm not sure if I understand your question, but initial=True on a forms.BooleanField just outputs `checked="checked"` in the html. Why would you put anything other than required=False on a booleanfield? Take a look at the note in [the official documentation on BooleanField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#booleanfield).

Comment: I want to redirect users to a search page using a single `GET` parameter to pass the search string. I want a bunch of other parameters to default to True but without being explicitly sent in the URL because this makes for a messy, long URL. Could not get this to work because these input fields default to `False`, not `True`, making it return 0 results.

So I edited the returned form, so it automatically sets the booleans I want to `True`. But apparently, `GET` does not send False booleans in the URL, so this method overwrites actual false values too. Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Essentially, I want it to only add GET parameters to the URL when they are False, because I want the default to be True. One can of course accomplish this by reversing the functionality of the buttons, so that unchecked means 'search that field' and checked means don't. But this makes the interface less intuitive for users. If there is a way to display the opposite value of checkboxes, that would work.